# How to automatically collapse xcode unit test results？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

now:
[image: now]

wish：
[image: wish]

Attempted to find the answer in the preferences settings, but found nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: Those don't seem to be your test results... Those seem to be the files in your project the functions in each file.

Comment: @Sweeper YES，I know, I expect to be able to collapse files by default and see coverage by file

Comment: Ah this is where the *coverage* is shown. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling, the default is the effect I want, but I don't know how to set it to the previous effect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).